# Mostrar apenas alguns números de páginas da paginação, em vez de todos

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, loop, paginação

Fiz uma paginação que está aparecendo todas as páginas:

[image: a paginaçao esta assim]

Preciso que fique parecido com isto:

```
<< < 1 2 3 4 5 6 7... 50 > >>

<< < 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ..60 > >>
```

Estou pesquisando e testando métodos diferentes, mas ainda não consegui nada que funcione.

```
<?php if ($num_pages > 1): ?>
<div class="paginador">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="first">Inicio</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="previous">Anterior</a>
  <?php for($i=1; $i<=$num_pages; $i++): ?>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="page-index page-<?php echo $i ?>"><?php echo $i ?></a>
  <?php endfor; ?>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="next">Próximo</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="last">Último</a>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

```js
  $('.paginador .page-index').on('click', function() {
    var classe = $(this).attr('class');
    classe = classe.replace('page-index ', '');
    $('tr.comprovante-pages').hide();
    $('tr.' + classe).show();
  });

  $('.paginador .first').on('click', function() {
    $('tr.comprovante-pages').hide();
    $('tr.page-1').show();
  });

  $('.paginador .last').on('click', function() {
    $('tr.comprovante-pages').hide();
    $('tr.last-page').show();
  });
```

Como eu posso incrementar esse código para transformar em uma paginação que vá alterando os números visíveis? Os botões de **próximo** e **anterior** não estão funcionando também, precisaria implementar isso também.